# Buscar responde con un renglon menos

Tags: php, mysqli, buscador

Utilizando practicamente el mismo php, excepto la parte de buscar, devuelve la lista completa, cuando agrego la parte de buscar, siempre falta uno, normalmente el 1º de la lista.

Id pac  Apellido    Nombres DNI
1   Alvarez Gomez   Alvaro  80100105

2   Bernardez Alvarez   Bernardo    80100100

3   Carles Alvarez  Carlos  80100101

4   Daniels Alvaro  Daniela 80100102

5   Estebanez Gomez Esteban 80100103

6   Alvarez Gomez   Alejo   80100104

```
<?php  
     include('99_conn.php');

$search = '';
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
}
$sql020 = "SELECT 00_idpac, 00_apellido, 00_nombres, 00_dni from $t00 where 00_apellido LIKE '%".$search."%' ";
if (!$res020 = $conexion->query($sql020) )
{
    echo $conexion->error;
    exit;
}
$fila = $res020->fetch_assoc();
    if($res020->num_rows > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Id </th>";
                echo "<th>Apellido</th>";
                echo "<th>Nombres</th>";
                echo "<th>DNI</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>. </th> </tr>";
        while($rw020 = $res020->fetch_array()){
            echo "<tr><td> </td> </tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw020['00_idpac'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw020['00_apellido'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw020['00_nombres'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rw020['00_dni'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Les agradecería cualquier orientación al respecto.
2º pregunta en un caso similar de hace muchos años, pude establecer que si presionaba cualquier parte del renglon, me remitiera a otra página con el id (por ejemplo, pego un solo renglon) como en este caso se incluye el html en el php y no a la inversa como en el ejemplo que pegué, ando medio perdida. 
Gracias.

> ```
> <td width="100"><div><a href="Gar_4_invc_liv.php?reemplazo=<?php echo $row_RS7['reemplazo']; ?>" target="_self" class="link"><?php echo $row_RS7['desc']; ?></a></div></td>
> ```

Comment: Que objetivo buscas con esta línea: $fila = $res020->fetch_assoc(); ya que no veo que uses dicha variable, si no me equivoco creo que al quitarla te saldrá la lista entera.

Comment: me olvidé de cambiarla es $rw020 en vez de $fila
pero evidentemente es superflua porque sigue dandome 4 Alvar en vez de 5

Comment: Tenias toda la razon, al quitarla anda perfecto MUCHAS GRACIAS,
¿Pero por qué?
sigue vigente la 2º pregunta como hacer que cada renglon devuelto se convierta en link.
Si son tan amables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por qué falta siempre el primero?

```
$fila = $res020->fetch_assoc();
```

**$res020** es un recurso de acceso a resultados y **fetch_assoc()** lee el primer registro y avanza el apuntador, después, en el while($rw020 = $res020->fetch_array()) inicias con el segundo registro y, automáticamente, avanza el apuntador para la siguiente iteración. Cuando se acaban los registros devuelve falso y termina el ciclo.

En resumen, los métodos **fetch_*()** leen el registro actual y avanzan el apuntador.

Cómo crear un link?

```
    while($rw020 = $res020->fetch_array()){
        // Modifica la ruta (pagina.php), variable (id)
        // y valor ($rw020['00_idpac'])
        // de acuerdo a tus necesidades
        $link = 'pagina.php?id=' . $rw020['00_idpac'];
        echo "<tr><td> </td> </tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            // Donde necesites el link:
            echo "<td><a href=\"$link\">" . $rw020['00_idpac'] . "</a></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rw020['00_apellido'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rw020['00_nombres'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rw020['00_dni'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Con esto se agregó el link solo en la primera columna, pero no hay problema si decides agregarla también en las demás.

Comment: muchas gracias, estuve tratando de armarlo y lo único que hice fue lio,.

Por lo que me dices el  fetch_assoc() puede eliminarte un registro que necesitán en una búsqueda o en un select. voy a tener que pegar una revisas.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No es que fetch_assoc() elimine un registro, simplemente "lo salta" y ya no lo toma en cuenta dentro del while.

Comment: Eso interpreté, así que si sólo es un registro vacio o innecesario el primero que se presenta, no se debe utilizar el fetch_assoc() porque al primero lo saltea. OK. Muchísimas gracias. tus respuestas y las de @Xavi ayudaron muchísimo. Ahora se me abre toda una serie de dudas existenciales pero vamos una por una en diferentes preguntas ja!